# Returning a List to a Function

Tags: function, list-comprehension

```
import random

def genList1():
     list1 = [x for x in range(100)]
     count = 0
     for count in list1:
        print(random.randint(2,25), end = " ")
     return

def main():
    print(genList1())

main()
```

The above code- Properly prints 100 random digits between 2 and 25, but returns "none" to the function. How can I return that list of 100 random digits to the function for us in the following code.

```
import random

def genList1(): 
    list1 = [x for x in range(100)]
    count = 0
    for count in list1:
        random.randint(2,25)
    return list1

def genList2():
    list1 = genList1()
    list2 = [x**2 for x in list1 if x % 2 == 0]
    return list2

def genList3():
    list2 = genList2()
    list3 = [0.5*x for x in list2]
    return list3

def genSum1_2():
    list2 = genList2()
    list3 = genList3()

    sum1 = 0
    number1 = 0
    for number1 in list2:
        sum1 = sum1 + number1

    sum2 = 0
    number2 = 0
    for number2 in list3:
        sum2 = sum2 + number2

    return sum1, sum2

def main():
    print("Here is List 1, which contains 100 random digits between 2 and 25: ")
    print(genList1())
    print(), print()
    print("Here is List 2, which is the cubes of all the even digits in List 1: ")
    print(genList2())
    print(), print()
    print("Here is List 3, which is all the digits in List 2 divided in half: ")
    print(genList3())
    print(), print()
    print("Here is the sum of the digits in List 2, and digits in List 3: ")
    print(genSum1_2())

main()
```

I have tried a few different alterations such as adding the return to in front of the print(random....) as well as tried assigning the print(random.....) to a variable then returning that variable...with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

def getRandList():
    return [random.randint(2,25) for x in xrange(100)]

print getRandList()
```

Or, if you want it to behave more like your original code...

```
import random

def genList1():
    randlist = [random.randint(2,25) for x in xrange(100)]
    for elem in randlist:
        print(elem, end = ' ')
    return randlist

def main():
    print(genList1())

main()
```

EDIT (to account for question in the comments below):

If you want to reuse the random numbers in that list, you've got a few options.

### Option 1: The Best Option

Pass the list in as an argument to subsequent functions.

```
def genList2(input_list):
    list2 = [x**2 for x in input_list if x % 2 == 0]
    return list2

def main():
    list1 = genList1()
    list2 = genList2(list1)
```

### Option 2: This Would Be Bad Programming Practice

If you want to be a developer other people on your team hate, you can do things like this a lot:

```
def genList1():
    global randlist
    randlist = [random.randint(2,25) for x in xrange(100)]
    for elem in randlist:
        print(elem, end = ' ')
    return randlist

def genList2():
    list2 = [x**2 for x in randlist if x % 2 == 0]
    return list2

def main():
    list1 = genList1()
    list2 = genList2()
```

Comment: If I print it, it changes the list for each function...how do I call upon the same list1 as it was originally generated???   (referencing the main code which has a more then 1 function)